# Apache Shiro - Assign role to groups with same prefix

Tags: java, ldap, shiro

I am trying to assign a role to ldap groups with same prefix, for example, all groups with starting with "ABC" have "admin" role. Can I configure this in shiro.ini file with "groupRolesMap"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no wildcard matching with the `groupRolesMap`. You could implement this functionality by overriding the `getRoleNamesForGroups` method in `ActiveDirectoryRealm`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Brian.